# Cannot connect to a local port anymore that is still being listened by a process

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I have a server application (unimrcpserver.exe) that is answering requests from client processes. This server process listens to several ports.
with `netstat -a` command I get the following lines for my process.

```
  TCP    192.168.10.65:2544     MERTB-PC:0             LISTENING  
  TCP    192.168.10.65:2554     MERTB-PC:0             LISTENING  
  TCP    192.168.10.65:9060     MERTB-PC:0             LISTENING
```

(netstat output is long I only put relevant lines here)

Normally when the system works I make requests to the server from these ports and each of them works fine.

When I was doing stress tests I saw a situation where the system no longer responded the my requests that I make through the port 2554.
 `netstat -a` still gives me the above lines so the server is somehow still listening to this port. When I run telnet on the same machine it gives an error :

```
telnet 192.168.10.65 2554  
  Connecting To 192.168.10.65...Could not open connection to the host, on port 2554: Connect failed
```

I also wrote a simple program with c++ to get the exact error message that the system generates to a connect() request. This time I get the following error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Additional info: Everything is on the same Windows machine. Firewall is disabled. This situation occurred only once when I am doing stress tests that sends multiple requests at the same time. Before the situation occurred the system handled to around 13000 requests, which took around half an hour.

So the question is : How can this situation occur? The port is being reported as "LISTENING" with netstat but I cannot connect to it. If it can be caused by a programming error what kind of an error can cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: Maybe there was a program that listened on these ports but shut down without 'clearing' them?

Comment: It does not look possible. It is my own workstation. I always run these kinds of tests and never saw another application that use the same port on this machine.

Comment: Then check for programs that can use these ports. You can run `ps ax | grep 2544`

Comment: Check the backlog parameter of the listen call, it should be something big. Or maybe you could not accept the incoming connection fast enough...

Comment: @ForceBru this is a windows machine. I checked with netstat -a and no other program is using this port.

Comment: @Malkocoglu That is a possibility because it is a program that use much CPU power. The listen call is made in a module I do not own (namely unimrcp) I've attached the system to the debugger after the hang but the debug info does not exist so I probably won't bee seeing that parameters value.

Comment: backlog parameter is used as SOMAXCONN. printed it during compile time and its value is 0x7fffffff for my build. (Defined in winsock2.h)

Comment: OK learned about SOMAXCONN and it does not seem to be the problem. its value is high enough.

Comment: @Mert, if it's Windows, please mention it somewhere.

Comment: http://ports.my-addr.com/tcp_port-udp_port-application-and-description.php?port=2544 http://ports.my-addr.com/tcp_port-udp_port-application-and-description.php?port=2554

Comment: Done. Btw. the problematic port is not 2544. It is 2554

Comment: You say the port is still listening, but is your listening thread still running? Is it blocked on a call to recv or accept? Perhaps the thread died, but the rest of your program continue to ran? On a side note, are you using SO_REUSEADDR?

Comment: I attached the process to visual studio debugger and could not see any thread(s) blocking on recv/accept. Still the other ports accept connections and I do not see their threads either. The debug databases of the unimrcp binaries are missing and I do not see the full call stack in the debugger view. And also the system has at least 2 threadpools in different subsystems and after the stress test I see more that 300 threads in the debugger it is hard to check everything in full detail. I may be missing things.

Comment: the part that is managing the sockets is an opensource project. i can check if it use SO_REUSEADDR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new connection can be "actively refused" under several conditions:

1. there is no `LISTENING` socket on the IP:Port being connected to.
2. there is a `LISTENING` socket, but its backlog of pending connections is full, so it cannot accept a new connection at that moment.
3. A firewall is blocking it. Though the firewall is more likely to use a different error, if it sends an error at all.

Since there is a `LISTENING` socket, #2 is the most likely/common case.  If so, it means the server app is not accepting clients from its backlog fast enough, if at all.

A client cannot differentiate between these conditions.  All it can do is detect the connect failure - `WSAECONNREFUSED` or `ECONNREFUSED`, depending on platform - and try again later.

Comment: Hmm so the socket is in LISTENING state. But the thread responsible for receiving the incoming connections has become somehow deadlocked. This caused the incoming connections queue whose size has been determined by SOMACONN to become filled. That explains the situation i think.

Answer (score 1):

> > So the question is : How can this situation occur? The port is being reported >>as "LISTENING" with netstat but I cannot connect to it. If it can be caused >>by a programming error what kind of an error can cause this kind of behavior?

Yes,It could be caused by a programming error on the server. I have seen it happening when the server's listening thread is deadlocked. The socket's state is "listening" but if the listening thread has some global state and is blocked on other threads waiting on a mutex to be released you will encounter this.
Also, like others here stated if the CPU is loaded due to your stress test and that might cause the server to refuse connections since the threads might be busy processing and the listening thread never got a chance to accept the connection.

Comment: Seems like the correct answer but Remy was faster. :) Thanks.

Comment: Another possibility is the listening thread may have crashed rather than deadlocked.